# React articles.map no es una fucion

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, reactjs, axios

Intento traer una serie de artículos desde mi api de node a mi proyecto de react.

Mi articulo tiene esta estructura:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "articles": [
        {
            "_id": "6111df44ba889526680b2338",
            "date": "2021-08-10T02:07:00.520Z",
            "title": "Thor",
            "content": "primer articulo creado para FAGUGARAMISA",
            "image": "l5Vq21AGl3hQjx_qBl5NeRwe.png",
            "author": "Juan Pablo Ramirez",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Ahora, estoy utilizando *axios* para traer los datos desde mi api pero quede estancado al momento de llamar el `.map`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Articulos = () => {

    const url = 'http://localhost:3900/api/articles/last';
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

    const getArticles = async () => {
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                setArticles(response.data)

                console.log(articles)

            })
    }

    useEffect(async () => {
        await getArticles();
    }, [])


    return (
        <section id="noticias">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <p className="title text-center">Noticias</p>

                     {
                        articles.map((article) => {
                            <div className="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 d-inline-block mx-5" key={article.id} style={{ 'maxWidth': '20rem' }}>
                                <div className="card-header sub-title text-center">{article.title}</div>
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h4 className="card-title">Primary card title</h4>
                                    <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                                        the card's content.</p>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-warning">Ir a la Noticia</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        })
                    } 



                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
export default Articulos;
```

El problema radica (en lo que indague) estoy tratando de pintar un array de objetos y **`Prototype.map`** funciona solo con *arrays*. Por lo que trate de convertir el array de objetos a array con `Object.key(articles)` pero no funcionó.

También trate de imprimir el resultado con un `for in` para no usar `.map` pero tampoco tuve éxito.

¿Alguien me puede dar una mano? Gracias

> Cabe aclarar dentro de *getArticles*, donde imprimo por consola articles, me trae los artículos sin problema

Comment: Desconozco _react_, pero me parece que el `return` se ejecuta antes de que la petición AJAX termine, por lo que los artículos aún no están disponibles. Tal vez [este artículo](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/react-loading-components-dynamically-hooks) pueda servirte como guía para crear la vista al finalizar la petición.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las **[reglas](https://dev.to/danialdezfouli/what-s-wrong-with-the-async-function-in-useeffect-4jne)** de `React`, es que el hook `useEffect` no puede ser asíncrono, pero sí puede anidar | ejecutar funciones asíncronas.

Por lo que debes cambiar la forma en que llamas a getArticles

```
useEffect(() => {
   (async () => await getArticles())()
}, [])
```

o también

```
useEffect(() => {
   const getArt = async () => await getArticles()
   getArt()
}, [])
```

Además, como ya te mencionaron, al renderizar el array, debe retornarse

```
{articles.map((item, index) => (
   <p key={index}>{item}</p>
))}
```

Simple :)

Nos comentas que tal te va y si fue lo que necesitabas.

Answer (score 0):

la función map debe retornar, por lo tanto debes establecer un "return":

```
return (
    <section id="noticias">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="jumbotron">
                <p className="title text-center">Noticias</p>
                           
                 {
                    articles.map((article) => {
                        return ( 
                        <div className="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 d-inline-block mx-5" key={article.id} style={{ 'maxWidth': '20rem' }}>
                            <div className="card-header sub-title text-center">{article.title}</div>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h4 className="card-title">Primary card title</h4>
                                <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                                    the card's content.</p>
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-warning">Ir a la Noticia</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       )
                    })
                } 

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
)
```

Espero que te funcione. Saludos